# How can I add a WHERE clause to a SELECT query?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

How can I write a SQL query to select a row using an integer in the WHERE clause?

Below is the piece of code where I want to use the query, but this is not working (no results are returned).

```
public Cursor forEditPurpose(int pos){

    db=this.getReadableDatabase();
   Cursor res =  db.rawQuery("SELECT name,phone FROM mecontact1 where _id = " + pos + "", null);

    return res;

}
```

This is my entire database code where I perform all operations which I have required:

```
public class ContactDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME="totalContact1.db";
    public static final  String TABLE_NAME="mecontact1";
    public static final  String NAME="name";
    public static final  String PHONE="phone";
    public static final  String UID="_id";


    public ContactDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            db.execSQL("create table mecontact1" +
                    "(_id integer primary key , name text, phone text)");
        }catch(android.database.SQLException e){
                System.out.println("table create nhi ho rha");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mecontact1");
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void insertContact(String nam,String mob,int autocrement){

        db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put(NAME,nam);
        contentValues.put(PHONE,mob);
        contentValues.put(UID,autocrement);

        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        db.close();
    }

    public Cursor showData(){

        db=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res =  db.rawQuery("SELECT  * FROM mecontact1", null);
        return res;

    }

    public Cursor nameData(String dataName){

        db=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res =  db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM mecontact1 WHERE name = '"+dataName+"'", null);
        return res;

    }

    public Cursor phoneData(String dataNumber){

        db=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res =  db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM mecontact1 WHERE phone = '"+dataNumber+"'", null);
        return res;

    }

    public Cursor phoneName(){

        db=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res =  db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM mecontact1 ", null);
        return res;

    }

    public void deleteContact(String d,int pos){
        db=this.getWritableDatabase();

        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM "+ TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + UID + " = " + pos +"");
        db.execSQL("UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " set " + UID + " = (" + UID + "-1) where " + UID + " > " + String.valueOf(pos));

    }

    public Cursor forEditPurpose(int pos){

        db=this.getReadableDatabase();
       Cursor res =  db.rawQuery("SELECT name,phone FROM mecontact1 where _id = " + pos + "", null);

        return res;

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by **not working**? Give more details!

Comment: @PrerakSola this query not return any row

Comment: @PrerakSola is this right query??

Comment: Are you certain you have data in your table with the `_id` value of what you passed in?

Comment: The query seems right but without the details like table structure, existing data in the tables, we cannot say why it's not working.

Comment: @PrerakSola yes table contain lot of  data

Comment: What data? Post some sample data in your question along with the table schema.

Comment: @PrerakSola wait i'll post

Comment: @PrerakSola please check m new with sqlite

Comment: @xyzrety We need to see sample data from the *database*.  (e.g.: Show the table structure and data rows in the `mecontact1` table.  Show what `int` value you're passing in to the method - you should also have a row in your table with the same `_id` value.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try;

```
  public Cursor forEditPurpose(int pos){

    db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    //don't forget the ? parameter in the selection
    Cursor res =  db.query(tableName,new String[]{"name","phone"},"_id =?",new String[]{""+pos},null,null,null);
    return res;

  }
```

Comment: Any reason for down voting this?

Comment: why m giving you down voting even this ans is solve my problem .again i say thanks for this help .and Malith Lakshan down voting is not mine

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to return cursor of query result this is full example but in your code you are probably missing cursor.moveToFirst();

```
public Cursor getById(int _id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT columns_to_return FROM table_name WHERE column_name = " + _id;
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    c.moveToFirst();

    return c;
}
```

If you need further explanation or help just ask.

Comment: @van Marincic exactly bro

Comment: I'm glad i could help you :) . By the way its  better practice to return object other than cursor.